# Design pattern name: Object of ClassA acts like a "class" for objects of ClassB

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have two classes* and I'm not sure what to call the relationship between them. Objects of *ClassA* are kind of like classes ("archetypes" or "patterns") for objects of *ClassB*.

- A `Song` has a title and artist.
- A `SongDimension` (*ClassA*) has a label (e.g. "Genre"; "Loudness") and a Set of `AcceptableValue`'s (e. g. "Classic Rock", "Classical", "Reggae"; "9", "10", "11").
- A `Song` has a Set of `SongDimensions`, and for each `SongDimension`, it has exactly one `SongDimensionValue` (*ClassB*), that tells which of the `AcceptableValue`'s for that `SongDimension` applies to this `Song`.

I'm trying to search for best practices using this pattern (or alternatives, if this isn't a good pattern to use), but I don't know what to call it. To me, it seems like objects of `SongDimension` are almost like a class for objects of `SongDimensionValue`. However, when I search the Internet using terms like that, I just get basic articles about what classes and objects are.

Is there a name for this pattern?

* I'm using Java terms (Class, Object), but this pattern could be applied in any OOP language.

Edit: thanks all for the answers. Reading them, I realized that I forgot to mention an important requirement. I'd like users to be able to create their own `SongDimension` instances at runtime, which I cannot predict at compile time.

For example, one user of the system might not care to use a the Genre `SongDimension` to classify `Songs` in their library. Instead, they create their own `SongDimension` with the label "Color" and give it acceptable values like Red, Yellow, and Black. This new `SongDimension` might not have any meaning to other users, but is meaningful to them, and that's the kind of flexibility I want to allow. They can still use the Loudness `SongDimension` independent of using Genre.

If it weren't for this requirement, enums and inheritance would indeed be the way to go. That's my bad for not including it in the first place.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean ... but could you give us some code snippets if you have any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This almost sounds like a [power type](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2005_09/article3/). Maybe try something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
class Artist {}
class Song {
    Song(String title,Artist artist,Map<Dimensions,Object> dimensionToValue) {
        this.title=title;
        this.artist=artist;
        this.dimensionToValue=dimensionToValue;
    }
    void setDimensionValue(Dimensions dimension,Object object) {
        try {
            if(dimensionToValue.containsKey(dimension)) {
                if(dimension.dimensionValues.contains(object)) {
                    System.out.println("set "+dimension+" to "+object);
                    dimensionToValue.put(dimension,object);
                }
                else throw new RuntimeException(object+" is illegal!");
            } else throw new RuntimeException(dimension+"is illegal dimension! for this song?");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("caught: "+e);
        }
    }
    Object getDimensionValue(Dimensions dimension) {
        return dimensionToValue.get(dimension);
    }
    String title;
    Artist artist;
    final Map<Dimensions,Object> dimensionToValue;
}
class Data {
    static final String[] genreValuesArray=new String[] {"country","rock"};
    static final Integer[] loudnessValuesArray=new Integer[] {1,2,3};
    static final Set<Object> genreValues=new LinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(genreValuesArray));
    static final Set<Object> loudnessValues=new LinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(loudnessValuesArray));
}
enum Dimensions {
    genre(Data.genreValues),loudness(Data.loudnessValues);
    Dimensions(Set<Object> dimensionValues) {
        this.dimensionValues=dimensionValues;
    }
    final Set<Object> dimensionValues;
}
public class So53724633_design_pattern_name_object_of_classa_acts_like_a_class_for_objects_of_classb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Dimensions,Object> map=new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Dimensions dimension=Dimensions.genre;
        map.put(dimension,null);
        Song song1=new Song("foo",new Artist(),map);
        Object value=song1.getDimensionValue(dimension);
        System.out.println("value of "+dimension+" is: "+value);
        song1.setDimensionValue(Dimensions.genre,Data.genreValuesArray[0]);
        value=song1.getDimensionValue(dimension);
        System.out.println("value of "+dimension+" is: "+value);
        song1.setDimensionValue(Dimensions.genre,"classical");
        song1.setDimensionValue(Dimensions.loudness,Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you compare this to my previous answer and let me know what advantage you see?

Comment: one contrast is that mine creates fewer classes.as the dimension enums get reused since there is only one instance of each.

Comment: Power type is just what I was looking for! Reading the article you linked, I found additional helpful search terms like "type object", "metaobject", "partitioned sets" and "clabject". However, I may be mistaken, but I'm not sure the code you posted actually illustrates the pattern, because power types should be defined at runtime, whereas the static arrays and enums you use are baked in at compile time, aren't they?

Comment: Enums are baked in. All of the dimension values are made at runtime or could be gotten from a database. My code does not illustrate the pattern but may be equivalent and may do what you want.

Comment: power type is also known as a type object (). the "The Dynamic Object Model (Property Lists)" at http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/analysis/top.htm sorta may be of interest.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/oom/patterns/new/classof.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for an enum.

`SongDimension` is an interface. `Genre`, `Loudness`, etc. are enum classes that implement the interface. Acceptable values are defined as the instances of the respective enums.

This fits your description nicely: the concrete implementations of `SongDimension` are enum classes whose instance objects define the ranges of acceptable values. Java is especially good for such a design because its enum classes are first-class citizens that support state and behavior like any other class.

This is not a design pattern, but it is a common coding idiom in Java.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Song mySong = new Song("My Favorite Song", "My Favorite Band",
                               Genre.Classic_Rock, Loudness.Eleven);
        System.out.println(mySong);
    }

    static class Song {
        final String title;
        final String artist;
        final Collection<SongDimension> dimensions = new HashSet<>();

        Song(String title, String artist, SongDimension... dimensions) {
            this.title = title;
            this.artist = artist;
            this.dimensions.addAll(Arrays.asList(dimensions));
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return "Song{ title=" + title + ", artist=" + artist +
                       ", dimensions=" + dimensions + " }";
        }
    }

    interface SongDimension {
        String label();
        String value();
    }

    enum Genre implements SongDimension {
        Classic_Rock, Classical, Reggae;

        @Override public String label() {
            return getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
        }
        @Override public String value() {
            return name().replace('_',' ');
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return label() + ':' + value();
        }
    }

    enum Loudness implements SongDimension {
        Nine(9), Ten(10), Eleven(11);

        final int volume;
        Loudness(int volume) {
            this.volume = volume;
        }

        @Override public String label() {
            return getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
        }
        @Override public String value() {
            return String.valueOf(volume);
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return label() + ':' + value();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; You seem to describe a common inheritance problem. There is a concept of SongDimension, and there are different other concepts that all share the fact that they are sub-types of SongDimension. I.e. loudness is a dimension of a song, as is tempo, as is genre etc. Lookup polymorphism and inheritance.

Now onto a lengthier answer.

### Huge disclaimer!

Please forgive any Java syntax errors. You seem to be most fluent in Java, so even though I am not a frequent Java coder, I thought it'd be best to speak Java in the answer. But the general pattern applies to many languages.

Towards the end of the answer I use some concepts that are a lot more advanced than I should probably speak about, but it might be inspirational or something.

---

In cases like this, I like to keep as much generality as possible. I also want to be able to impose any restrictions that makes sense, like for instance what you suggests with certain allowed values, but also in regards to what computations are allowed.

I would think of this problem like this:

There is a Song class. Each song is then an instance of that class.

The song class has a collection of objects of type SongDimension:

```
public class Song {
    public string title;
    public string artist;
    public List<SongDimension> songDimensions;
}
```

The SongDimension class is an abstract class with the following signature

```
public abstract class SongDimension {
    public abstract string GetValue();
}
```

Then for each type of dimension, you might want to generate enums for your acceptable values, or apply custom logic like in the case for loudness, like this:

```
public enum Genres {
    ClassicRock, Classical, Reggae
}


public class Genre extends SongDimension {
    private Genres _genre;

    public string GetValue(){
        switch(_genre) {
           case ClassicRock: return "Classic Rock";
           default: return _genre.name();
        }
    }

    public Genre(Genres whichGenre) {
        _genre = whichGenre;
    }
}

public class Loudness extends SongDimension {
    private int _loudness;

    public string GetValue(){
        return String.valueOf(_loudness);
    }

    public int GetIntValue() {
        return _loudness;
    }

    public Loudness(int howLoud) {
        if(howLoud < 9 || howLoud > 11) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        _loudness = howLoud;
    }

    // Add more relevant operations on the value here,
    // maybe you can take differences of loudnesses for instance?
}
```

To use it all you could create a couple of songs like this:

```
Song EineKleineNachtMusik = new Song();
EineKleineNachtMusik.songDimensions.Add(new Genre(Genres.Classical));
EineKleineNachtMusik.songDimensions.Add(new Loudness(9));

Song BackInBlack = new Song();
BackInBlack.songDimensions.Add(new Genre(Genres.ClassicRock));
BackInBlack.songDimensions.Add(new Loudness(11));

for(SongDimensions d : EineKleineNachtMusik.songDimensions){
    System.out.println(d.GetValue());
}
/// prints:
/// Classical
/// 9
```

The greatest value of all this is that it lets you have the various pieces of information about the song not as strings, but as proper objects. The risk of using string placeholders for values and types is that you might end up with different interpretations of what for instance "11" really means. Even though you might only be able to assign the values "9", "10" or "11" as a "Loudness", nothing stops you from later on treat the "10" as something entirely different by mistake, e.g. the song length in minutes.

This way we can create objects that are semantically sound, and incorporate custom logic into the different kinds of traits. We could for instance have the Loudness class implement `Comparable<Loudness>` (naïve implementation for sure. Not checking for null for instance):

```
public class Loudness extends SongDimension implements Comparable<Loudness> {
    ...
    // Same as before with the addition of the following:
    @Override public int compareTo(Loudness that) {
        if(_loudness < that.GetIntValue()) return -1;
        if(_loudness == that.GetIntValue()) return 0;
        if(_loudness > that.GetIntValue()) return 1;
    }  
}
```

*I will now walk onto some really thin ice, given that I'm not a Java developer. This will MOST PROBABLY contain errors, so please feel free to bash all you want in the comments. But this further illustrates the point that by using some minimal boilerplate, one can have many benefits at once, enforcing proper values for the dimensions, have custom appropriate logic implemented, different for each type of dimension etc.*

With the addition of a little helper method in the `Song` class to retrieve a particular type of dimension:

```
 public class Song {
    ...
    // same as above, with the addition of:

    public <T extends SongDimension> T GetDimension(Class<T> dimType) {
       return songDimensions.stream().filter(dim -> dim instanceof 
            dimType).Collect(Collectors.toList()).iterator().next()
    }
}
```

We may then compare two songs like this:

```
Loudness l1 = EineKleineNachtMusik.GetDimension(Loudness.class);
Loudness l2 = BackInBlack.GetDimension(Loudness.class);

if(l1 != null && l2 != null && l1.compareTo(l2) < 0) {
   System.out.println("Yup, BackInBlack is the louder of the two");
}
```

Comment: This appears to be essentially the same as my previous answer, only more verbose.

Comment: Yes, I started answering, then had to go away for some time, and when I came back and hit submit, you had already answered. I thought about taking it away, but I think it has some points on why proper types instead of simple enums are useful. A genre is not very similar to a loudness, so they should be modelled differently. The only thing they share is the fact that they are things a Song can have. Modeling either of those with the only behavior that there are limitations to what kinds they can be seems really limiting. A loudness could be an argument to an amplifier, where as a genre couldn't

Comment: @jaco0646, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Maybe one should have used the Decorator pattern or something. I mean, the primary thing a loudness is, is probably not a SongDimension. It is first and foremost a subjective measure of sound pressure. It might have a unit to go with the value. Any sound can have loudness, not just songs. Maybe instead using the Decorator pattern to turn various classes into SongDimensions whenever needed. A Duration certainly is a SongDimension. No need to create a dumb enum paired with a string value for that, when Java already has this class implmemented. Make it fit into the SongDimension scheme instead.

Answer (score 0):

I try to provide a solution that do not need any `Enum` because you are look for:

> I'm using Java terms (Class, Object), but this pattern could be applied in any OOP language.

## Maybe a Logical Error?

Maybe the given problem includes a logical error:

> A Song has a Set of SongDimensions
>   [...]
>   A SongDimension (ClassA) has a label (e.g. "Genre"; "Loudness")

This would mean that a `Song`-object could have at the same time multiple different genres with different loudness.

But if you think in code, what you actually want to say is `new Song("mj", "billie jean", new Rock(), new LoudnessLevel8())`;

But in your given problem it would be possible that *Billie jean* is *reggae* with loudness *6* and at the same time it is *rock* with loudness `8`.

Please correct me in the comments if I'm wrong.

## Solution without the Logical Error

### Song

> A Song has a title and artist. A Song has a <strike>Set of</strike> SongDimensions.

```
class Song {
  private String title;
  private String artist;
  private SongDimension songDimension;
}
```

### SongDimension

For a `SongDimension` we need `Genre` and `Loudness`. For these we can create an abstract and than multiple concrete types. Here an example for `Genre`:

```
interface Genre { /**/ }

class Classic implements Genre { /**/ }

class Rock implements Genre { /**/ }
```

These concrete types (like `Classic` and `Rock`) are your `AcceptableValue`'s

Let's try to create a new song:

```
SongDimension rockBy8= new SongDimension(new Rock(), new LoudnessLevel8());
Song billieJean = new Song("mj", "billie jean", rockBy8);
```

### SongDimensionValue

I think there is no need for a `SongDimensionValue`.. correct me in the comments

Comment: You seem to have confused a `Set` with a `List`. A Set is a collection of _unique_ elements. It cannot "have at the same time multiple different genres with different loudness." A Set may contain at most one of each `SongDimension`. Also note that enums are common across languages. Java's happen to be more powerful than most; but they are by no means unconventional.

Comment: "A Set may contain at most one of each SongDimension" -> This is my sentance with other words. I'm not confused between List and Set..For me it makes no sence that a song has multiple SongDimension

Comment: You make a great point about equality. However, a many to one relationship is still necessary because users can pick and choose which `SongDimensions` they use to describe `Songs`. For example, a `Song` can have a Genre `SongDimension` but not a Loudness, or vice versa. I think a `Map` with `SongDimension` keys and `SongDimensionValues` as values would be more appropriate than a `Set`